# Discord.JS - List all files within a directory as one message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am having an issue where I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have written a Discord bot from Discord.JS that needs to send a list of file names from a directory as one message. So far I have tried using fs.readddir with path.join and fs.readfilesync(). Below is one example.

```
        const server = message.guild.id;
        const serverpath = `./sounds/${server}`;
        const fs = require('fs');
        const path = require('path');

        const directoryPath = path.join('/home/pi/Pablo', serverpath);

        fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            }
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                message.channel.send(file);
            });
        });
```

Whilst this does send a message of every file within the directory, it sends each file as a separate message. This causes it to take a while due to Discord API rate limits. I want them to all be within the same message, separated with a line break, with a max of 2000 characters (max limit for Discord messages).

Can someone assist with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [fs.readdirSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options), it will return an array of the file names in the given directory. Use [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the files down to the ones that are JavaScript files (extentions ending in ".js"). To remove ".js" from the file names use [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to replace each `".js"` to `""` (effectively removing it entirely) and use [Array#join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join them into a string and send.

```js
const server = message.guild.id;
const serverpath = `./sounds/${server}`;
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const directoryPath = path.join('/home/pi/Pablo', serverpath);

const files = readdirSync(directoryPath)
   .filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.js'))
   .map(fileName => fileName.replace('.js', ''));
   .join('\n');
message.channel.send(files);
```

---

Regarding handling the sending of a message greater than 2000 characters:
You can use the [Util.splitMessage()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage) method from Discord.JS and provide a `maxLength` option of `2000`. As long as the number of chunks needed to send is not more than a few you should be fine from API ratelimits

```js
const { Util } = require('discord.js');

// Defining "files"

const textChunks = Util.splitMessage(files, {
   maxLength: 2000
});

textChunks.forEach(async chunk => {
   await message.channel.send(chunk);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What would the best way to also omit the file extension from the list?

Comment: To filter down to files that *do not* end in `.js` use the [Logical Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) operator `!`. Example : `.filter(fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.js'))`

Comment: Sorry, badly worded.. I want it to send the file names without the .js at the end. Bad English I am sorry!

Also, I am getting an error for the 2000 character limit I stated in my initial post, best way to separate messages to a max of 2000 characters?

Comment: @Cazed My mistake, I misunderstood the question. Your English was fine. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Built an array of strings (names of files) then join with "\n".

```
let names = []
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    }
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        names << file
        
    });
});
message.channel.send(names.join("\n"));
```